# Jade templates django - Use captured url value in urls.py

Tags: django, pug, pyjade

I have "static" javascript templates I want to serve with my Django application. Usually you put them in the static folder and that's it. The problem here is the templates aren't really static, they are **jade**(pyjade) templates that need to be pre-compiled.
My plan is having the templates inside a sub-directory of the app's *templates* dir, lets call it *jstemplates*, and then serve them from the `urls.py` file like this:

```
...
url(r'^jstemplates/(?P<template>.*)', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=<captured_name>)),
...
```

but how can I get the captured template name?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking it better, I suppose the captured attribute won't be available until view's instantiation so I made a sub-class of TemplateView called JsTemplateView.

```
class JsTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return "jstemplates/%s.jade" % self.kwargs['template']
```

and added the corresponding line in urls.py `url(r'^jstemplates/(?P<template>.*)', JsTemplateView.as_view()`